# Get all comments by myself using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've got a basic app working that contacts the Facebook Graph API and return some account info. I'm looking to provide my access token and return all comments I've ever made on any page/wall/etc. Is this possible? If so, can someone point me in the right direction on what I'll use to do this? Thanks!

Comment: that is not possible, there is no api for it

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I just tried downloading my facebook data (comments) to see if it supplies an ID I can use to use with the delete api and it looks like it doesn't supply one, is that right? So frustrating!

Comment: afaik you can only delete stuff you posted with an app. and posting to a user profile is not even possible anymore with the api, so...